# Basic Trigger Work

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Employee and Department

Employee Table has the following columns

```
Name
SSN
Salary
Dept_No
Supervisor_SSN
```

Department Table has the following columns

```
Dept_Name
Dept_No
Total_Salary
Manager_SSN
```

I need to write a trigger that so that when a new Employee is inserted, we update the Departments Total salary to include the new Employee's salary. This is what I've come up with, but apparently 'WHERE' is not allowed in a Trigger. Any help is appreciated.

```
USE `mydb`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Employee_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `Employee` FOR EACH ROW
WHERE NEW.dno = department.Dno
SET department.total_sal = department.total_sal + NEW.salary;
```

The error I am getting is

```
syntax error, unexpected WHERE
```

Comment: paste the full error page

Comment: @jmail I've included the only information available about the error.

Comment: you should add the `delimiter //` and try

Answer (score 0):

After `FOR EACH ROW` you should be writing normal sql statements just like in a stored procedure.

Read more about syntax at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

your creating normal sql query you should mention like the `sample format`:

you should mention the correct format the `delimiter` and `for each row`

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html**

**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html**